# Residual plot in the logarithmic model.

Tags: statistics, linear-transformations, statistical-inference, residue-calculus, mathematical-modeling

We've got some data containing two variables, where $x$ is the predictor and $y$ is the response variable. We make a model of the form of:
$$y=\alpha+\beta \cdot x + \epsilon$$
Then we see that in the residual plot (residuals vs. $\hat{y}$) the variance is increasing as $\hat{y}$. We then decide to transform our model to a logarithmic form, i.e.:
$$log(y)=\alpha+\beta \cdot x + \epsilon$$
And now my question is: When performing a residual plot analysis, do we plot residuals vs. $\hat{log(y)}$ or $\hat{y}$?

Comment: Residuals are differences between what is what is observed and what is predicted by the regression equation. So if you're regressing log(y) on x, then you'd use predicted  and observed log(y) to find the residuals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should plot them against the log (y) as these are the residuals that need to be tested for the logarithmic form